# python elements in line without raw_input()

Tags: python, inputstream

I have an input stream of numbers

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 and it goes on......
```

now in python, we have to take input by `raw_input()` and then `map(int,raw_input.split())` and then do whatever processing one has to do.

for eg.

```
n = map(int,raw_input().split())
for i in n:
    print i%2==0
```

So in the above code, i have first taken all inputs, converted them to integer and ran a loop to check if each integer is even number or not.

I can do the same thing in Java, but now i can simply give result just as soon as I get input.

for eg. Assuming number of inputs ( `n` ) is given, the following program, takes input from the above given input feed and keep on giving requisite output.

```
for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ){
    n = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(n%2==0);
}
```

I want to know, if there is some method in python by which we can take `n` inputs from a line and keep processing it in continuation.

And how are the two above programs differ performance wise.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this (assumes `n` is already set)

```
in = raw_input().split()
for i in range(n):
    i = int(in[i])
    print(i%0 == 0)
```

This is analogous to the Java code, but like the Java code, this will raise an error if there are fewer than `n` numbers, or if any of the items in the input are not integers.

Comment: hmm... i know that method and most have to do it that way only. What i want is that i shud take input for every integer, here in this code first you have taken the complete string, split it and then use it. i do not want to use the split function, i just want to take the input integer as it comes.

Comment: Your comment doesn't make any sense.. the Java code is tokenizing on whitespace also, it just does it inside the nextInt method. You can't get the raw data without doing some changes to your tty on unix and I don't know what you'd need to do to avoid cooking your input on a windows machine..